# Ansible Python interpreter Issue

Tags: ansible

Im trying to change the Python interpreter as Im in a virtual environment.
But also I will be deploying the venv on a Jenkins server that only has python2. Hence....

```
# grep python ansible/ansible.cfg
interpreter_python = ./venv/bin/python2

ansible --version | grep "python version"
  python version = 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever find out what you did wrong? From the documentation, it looks like your approach of setting interpreter_python in ansible.cfg should also work

Comment: Sorry cant recall. To confirm now I dont need the setting. I just enter my venv, and ensure the setting permissions are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the ["Using Python3 on the managed machines with commands and playbooks"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/python_3_support.html#using-python-3-on-the-managed-machines-with-commands-and-playbooks) section of the Docs. The piece is  for `python3` but it truly doesn't matter which version of python you end up using. On that article you'll see this quote:

> To explicitly configure a Python 3 interpreter, set the `ansible_python_interpreter` inventory variable at a group or host level to the location of a Python 3 interpreter, such as `/usr/bin/python3`. The default interpreter path may also be set in `ansible.cfg`.

So, just set the `ansible_python_interpreter` at the level that makes sense for your `hosts`.

Answer (score -1):

Install Ansible with

```sh
pip3 installl ansible
```

So, it will work with Python 3+.